# How to dismiss and call keyboard correctly in objective - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

I'm working on a TODO-app for IOS with objective C and last version of xcode.

My problem occur when I try to add a new category group (pressing on a floating plus button):

- the first time keyboard and the view above (that contains textview and a "arrow up-done button") show up correctly (and dismiss correctly after I click on done button) but when I try again to add a category group by clicking on floating button ,the keyboard and the relative view don't show up. (so keyboard appear only once correctly).

Some code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
 {
   [Super viewDidLoad];

   _GroupTextView.delegate=self; 
   
 }
-(IBAction) PlusButtonPressed: (UIButton *) sender
{ 

   _obscureView.hidden= false;
    _ViewKeyboard.hidden=false;

   _GroupTextView.inputAccessoryView = _VievKeyboard; 
   
    [_GroupTextView becomeFirstResponder];
}
-(IBAction)DonePressed:(UIButton *) Sender
     {
     
        _obscureView.hidden= True;
        _ViewKeyboard.hidden= True;
        [_GroupTextView resignFirstResponder];
     }
```

some photos:

[Before press plus button for add category group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v8xz.jpg)

[after I've clicked on plus button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rhyO.png)

[When I click again on plus button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E5i2.jpg)

i've checked and the view can become first responder, but keyboard with custom view don't show up.

Comment: don't confuse yourself, try to write variables starting with lowercase and classes starting uppercase. you call "Super" which should throw warnings and is _GroupTextView a class or variable? And when done, is _VievKeyboard not still inputAccessoryView of _GroupTextView. So keyboard is hidden itself but the given frame meant for the dialog or keyboard is still there.

Comment: if possible, in -(IBAction)donePressed: check if property inputAccessoryView of _GroupTextView != nil and if _GroupTextView.inputAccessoryView.hidden = YES; you need to handle this situation. In short, show us interface and implementation of _GroupTextView class.

Comment: @OlSen Thank you for your answer, naming convention is ok (uppercase and lowercase), first of all _GroupTextView is an outlet that I connected to a TextView ( defined using user interface in main.storyboard ) ; this GroupTextView is contained in another custom View (_ViewKeyboard ) which is put above keyboard using inputAccessoryView; now , I checked what you suggested me to do and the results are: property of _inputAccessoryView of _GroupTextView!=nil ;_GroupTextView.inputAccesoryView.hidden= FALSE ;

Comment: Davide - write what you like but you are not confusing yourself, you are confusing us! He he he he. While you are at it, in Objective-C you do not really use true and false, rather go with YES and NO, but then again, under the hood it is all the same ...